# Getting code from Github to Netbeans

Tags: git, github, netbeans

I'm trying to learn Git and find it confusing. I've been practicing and have a few repos on Github. I reinstalled my OS and now would like to get back all the source code so I can continue working on it. I use Netbeans. What's the best way to do this? Is it

1. create an empty project in Netbeans
2. clone the repo using Git

Or

1. clone repo using git
2. import project from existing source code into netbeans

Or use netbeans built in git support? Or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***typical workflow*** is (no. 2):

1. **Clone Git repository** — whether you use NB, terminal or UI doesn't matter, the result is the same<sup>1)</sup>. Use your personal preference here.
2. **Open or create a project** — what to do here ***depends*** on the project, language and build tool. If it's eg. a maven or ant project (or a NetBeans project type of course) you can ***directly open*** it; for eg. a makefile, cmake or similar project you can create a ***new project from existing source***. If there's just plain code, do the the latter one.

---

<sup>1)</sup> If you clone via Netbeans, you sometimes get an option to directly open or create the project from the source you've cloned. This however depends on used language, project etc. In the end there's no difference if you choose to use this or open the project manually.

Comment: So you clone the repo before you create the project. Do you create a folder to clone the code to, then when it is imported to a project you delete the folder?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. -- The clone will create a new folder itself. So eg. your are in the directory `abc/def/github/` and clone the repository *my-project*. This will create ` […]/def/github/my-project/` – source files are in there. After this, just create your project in `my-project` as usual; nothing to delete here.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: Netbeans *wont* copy / move any files from the cloned projects folder. It only uses the available source and project files (or creates those if necessary).